# gadgets.Prefs in type url Google Gadget

Tags: javascript, google-gadget

Is it possible to access gadgets.Prefs in content of type="url"?

```
<Content type="url" href="remote address"></Content>
```

gadgets.Prefs is set in content of configuration

```
<Content type="html" view="configuration">
```

Answer (score 0):

No, i do not think so. I am working around this area at the moment but from what i have read and experimented with the type="url" is a complete sandbox around the app that it contains. cookies and therefore are not preserved either and there is no interaction, other than to display the external app in the iFrame.

Comment: I could obtain the pref parameters in GET request, when the gadget loads. Please check the GET that comes from browser and also include another view in gadget that manages the persistence of pref parameters along with "url" content type.

Comment: @dhaval : you should post this comment as an answer, and accept it if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ig.gmodules.com/gadgets/js/auth-refresh:core:core.iglegacy:core.io.js?container=ig&amp;nocache=0&amp;debug=0&amp;c=0&amp;v=4a066efd97777d0aba7a8678d4913ba8&amp;sv=10&amp;jsload=0"></script>
```

It has been working well on my asp.net page.